# Does tetrahedral complex in R^3 with "2-spherical" boundary have to be a 3d ball?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $S$ be a finite set of tetrahedrons in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $S$ be tetrahedral complex in a sense that if two tetrahedrons intersect, the intersection is a face of both. In what follows we view tetrahedrons and their faces as *closed* sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let the underlying topological space $|S|$ (domain occupied by all tetrahedrons with the topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^3$) be manifold with boundary.

Let $T$ be arbitrary subset of tetrahedrons from $S$. Let $\partial T$ consist of those 2-simplices, which are faces of exactly one tetrahedron from $T$. Let $|\partial T|$ be the underlying topological space.

Suppose $|\partial T|$ is homeomorphic to a 2-sphere. Does it follow that $T$ is homeomorphic to a 3d ball? If not, what would be a counter-example?

Comment: Yes, this is Alexander's theorem.   This answer was given as part of an answer to your previous question as well.  

Comment: I am voting to close as "spam".

Comment: In that answer there was additional requirement that $|T|$ is a manifold with boundary. I asked in comments if this requirement could be dropped, and somebody answered "no" without any explanation.

Comment: I would have thought that if a collection of tetrahedra in $\mathbb R^3$ has a manifold boundary, then it is itself a manifold with boundary, since all non-manifold points would have to involve the boundary.

Comment: Jim, yes, that's why I asked if the requirement on $|T|$ could be dropped.

Comment: I think that I can prove that any 'simplicially-interior' point $p$ ($p\in |T|$ but $p\notin |\partial T|$) is ``topologically-interior'' (there exists open ball $O$ such that $p\in O \subset |T|$). Or is this obvious anyway?